# List of Websites blocking TOR

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am currently doing my thesis and for that I need list of sites which are blocking tor. It would be nice if someone can provide me list.

Comment: But I want list of sites and there is no list in answer of that question. They have mentioned very few examples to describe in how many ways we can block tor. Can I get list of sites out  of top 1 million sites which blocks tor?

Comment: You can (and should) make this list by yourself. @mirimir did something and posted it as answer to the question which was mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search "block Tor" on Tor wiki (trac.torproject.org), you'll  get lots of interesting results. Unchecking the tickets box might be helpful.